# ASP.NET MVC : Find all action methods that returns view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

For a given view (or partial view), is there an easy way to find all action methods that returns that view?
This would be kind of equivalent to right click a function or a class and press "Find all references".

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to achieve that. Why do you need it? What more general problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: What could work is to look for the usages of the ViewModel. But this might either return too many actions if the ViewModel is resused or too few if the VIewModel is not instantiated in the controller (e.g. if you use Automapper).

Comment: just do a find all in files for the partial view name

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I am trying to navigate through a project that was created by other people. I just feel that it would help me a lot.

Comment: @MarkHomer Yeah, well that works for partial views. Still, I really would like to just get all methods that returned it.

Comment: @Mark Homer: string search might be problematic if the View has a generic name like "Index.cshtml"

Comment: Maybe this is not really a problem. I would just like to be able to right click a view and find all places that it was returned.

Comment: I think that it will very much depend on how the project is organized. For example you could have views or partials returned by custom action filters and not actions, do you need those returned as well? There are many places outside the action that are part of the MVC request execution pipeline that can return views.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have not thought about that.

Comment: That's why I said that what you are trying to achieve is not a simple task at all to be done for every possible MVC project.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Well, what I would like is to include every single place that returns a given view. Would that be hard to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, I understood that and as I already said it is not an easy task for the general case :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). There is "Find Usages" at the top of the toolbar.

**Toolbar;**
[image]

1. Selected `View`
2. At the tool bar selected "Find Usages Advanced"

**And the result;**
[image]

Hope helps,